# ASP.NET Core - Conditionally available dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a written a simple ASP.NET Core service which provides information about the  current user (derived from the `User` claims). I have another service which provides a user-specific view of a multi-tenant database.

There are some situations where I'd like this database view service to be injected into a controller, but of course I don't know if the user will have successfully authenticated or not, so I won't be able to instantiate it.

Is there an established pattern I should follow for this kind of situation?

Obviously I could throw an exception, but this'd result in a 500 error being returned where it feels like it should be the role of a controller to deem whether an operation can / cannot continue without this service being available. Or should I just have a service that boxes the value and have it be `null` if it couldn't be instantiated for whatever reason?

Thanks.

Comment: i think boxing the view under a service that recive the user as a dependency is the go-to approach

Comment: if possible, please show a sample code of what you've tried so far